# Make tables the same width

Tags: r

I have 4 tables , A,B,C,D. All of them have 6 rows but A is 30 columns wide, B is 35 columns wide, C is 40 columns wide and D is 25 Columns wide. I have created a script that requires all the tables to be the same width to work. How can I add blank columns to tables A,B,D to make them the same length

shared_cols <-rep(0,length(colnames(A))) 
for (i in 1:length(shared_cols))  {

```
  for (j in 1:shared_cols)) {
    if (colnames(A)[i] == colnames(B)[j] |
        colnames(A)[i] == colnames(C)[j] |
        colnames(A)[i]  == colnames(D)[j]) {
      shared_cols[i] <- shared_cols[i] + 1

    }
  }
```

Tables are data.frame type.

I want the loop to run through every element, checking every colname in A with the colnames in B,C,D. The current problem is that either A is too wide thus meaning that it causes an error for going out of dimension bounds of B/C/D or A is less wide than the other ones thus not checking every column name.

Fix: Used intersect instead of element by element comparison.

```
  for (i in 1:length(colname(A))) {
    if (length(intersect(colnames(A)[i],colnames(B)))>0 |
        length(intersect(colnames(A)[i],colnames(C)))>0 |
        length(intersect(colnames(A)[i],colnames(D)))>0) {
      shared_cols[i] <- shared_cols[i] + 1

    }
  }
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  It is not clear whether the tables are `data.frame`, `table` or `matrix`

Comment: Probably you need `intersect` `shared_cols <- Reduce(intersect, list(names(A), names(B), names(C), names(D)))`

Comment: Thank @akrun, i used intersect instead

Comment: okay and what happened

Comment: Instead of checking element by element, I used intersect thus removing the need of a for loop. This means i don't need to worry anymore about the different widths.